# Versioning files error, using Magnolia in java with apache chemistry and standard CMIS

Tags: java, eclipse, cmis, magnolia

i try to make a file as major version in a remote Magnolia repository. For this propose I am using java on Eclipse EE IDE, libraries from org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.* and REST architecture.
The code that I use for make a document is the following:

```
Folder parent = rute.get(rute.size() - 1);

Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);

// content
byte[] content = "".getBytes();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl
        (nombre, BigInteger.valueOf(content.length), "text/plain", stream);

// create a major version
try {
    parent.createDocument(properties, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR);
} catch (CmisConstraintException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And it throw the Exception "Versioning not supported for cmis:document". The same code but conected to Alfresco instead of Magnolia works perfectly, so I think is a problem with Magnolia config, but I can't find the problem. Sombody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you don't have cmis:document type registered in Magnolia at all. All content in Magnolia is out of the box of mgnl:content type. And since versioning in Magnolia works differently than that in Alfresco, I would not even try to make version this way. Actually, much simpler, if you are using latest version of Magnolia you can invoke VersionCommand over REST and tell Magnolia to version whatever page you need to be versioned directly.